# Understanding "\_W*" in vim regex

Tags: regular-expression

I have been going through some [answers to a vimgolf](https://vimgolf.com/challenges/540629666a1e4000020d9e5a#5946a26411266f0006000005), and stumbled upon this regex:

```
:s/\_W*/-/g|x<CR>
```

Which converts

```
abcdefghijklm
```

to

```
-a-b-c-d-e-f-g-h-i-j-k-l-m-
```

The regex (without unrelated keystrokes) is `/\_W*/-/`. The manual indicates that:
 `\W` stands for `non-word character:       [^0-9A-Za-z_]`

`\_x   Where "x" is any of the characters above: The character class with
    end-of-line added`

So `\_W` is non-word characters with end-of-line added.

How does that put the dashes between the characters? Is there a hidden metacharacter between each character in vim text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a question of hidden character, the trick comes from the `*` combined with the flag `g`:

Specifying `*` after a character classe will match "zero or more" items (which includes an empty string): between `a` and `b` there is zero non-word character, thus `\W*` will match this "not existing space".

For example you could also have used `\_s*` or `\_d*` and still get the same result since you match zero items of the class.

Answer (score 0):

To add to what statox mentioned above, if you want to avoid matching against the "not existing" space, use `\+` instead of `*` to match one or more instances of the non-word character:

```
:s/\_W\+/-/g
```